# Set ruby version in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

I can set ruby version in `Gemfile` as follows:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

But what if I want to have a particular version as `2.0.0-p353`?

When I add it to `Gemfile`, I get:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your `Gemfile` specified 2.0.0-p353
```

Is it even possible to set a particular version?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Version 1.3 and earlier of Bundler you [couldn’t specify the patchlevel](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html):

> The `ruby` directive explicitly leaves out the ability to specify a patch level. Ruby patches often include important bug and security fixes and are extremely compatible.

This changed in version 1.5, [the docs now say](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile_ruby.html):

> In the `ruby` directive, `:patchlevel` is optional, as patchlevel releases are usually compatible and include important security fixes. The patchlevel option checks the `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` constant, and if not specified then bundler will simply ignore it.

So you can specify the patchlevel like this:

```
ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '353'
```

Comment: Just noticed that you need to specify `patchlevel` as a string. Otherwise, `bundler` would error: `The Ruby patchlevel in your Gemfile must be a string`.

Comment: @AlexSmolov it looks like you’re right. The docs must be wrong. A string is used in the [Gemfile manual](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html) though.

Answer (score 17):

If anyone is looking to be reminded of how to *NOT* specify a minor version, (yeah call me a noob) you could do:

```
ruby ">=2.2"
```

which would allow 'bundle install' call with ruby 2.2.4.

Comment: I can't find the doc for this but can find this changelog https://bundler.io/v1.12/whats_new.html#ruby-version-locking. You can also do like this `ruby "~> 2.2"`

Comment: @LinhDam, did you mean `~> 2.2.0`?