# Installing a ruby app on a machine with multiple users

Tags: ruby

When trying to install a ruby app via bundler, how does your system decide which version of Ruby to use?

Will I run into problems if i use a version of Ruby installed in a directory I do not have access to? If so, how do I ensure I use a version of Ruby installed in the correct directory.

---

For those voting to close, I am not looking for debugging help. I am looking for an understanding of how bundler decides which version of Ruby to use.

Comment: What do you mean by ruby app? You mean a ruby file that you're running with `ruby file.rb`? A gem? A web app? If you go to the terminal and run `ruby -v` what's the output. We need a bit more information to help you out.

Comment: I'm not looking for a bug fix, I'm looking for an aswer to the question.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about a bug fix...I'm trying to get more information to properly answer your question. You have a ruby app...what kind of ruby app...what is the ruby app's target ruby version? you can find which ruby version you have/are running by running `ruby -v`...anything further will need more information from you. What you gave us does not give us much.

Comment: Maybe I should edit the question to rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has a Gemfile (most will) you can specify ruby version on Gemfile.

See this question  [Set ruby version in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427515/set-ruby-version-in-gemfile)